# D3JS Group / Prepare transition?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm posting because I didn't find a nice solution yet and google don't help me so much this time.

http://jsfiddle.net/CUQaN/5/

As you can see on the JSFiddle link, I have a lin/area chart. I update this graph with new data. But I have a problem with the transitions.. My 'circle' do not move in the same time than the lines/areas and I think that it's due to the time running the code.

I would like to move everything in the same time. How can I do that ?

I thought about a group of transition, I mean, prepare every objects/elements and insert them into a group, and then, when every objects are in the group, trigger the transitions. But I couldn't find something like that :

```
svg.selectAll("circle")
    .prepareTransition()
    .insertInGroup('firstGroup')
    .attr("cy", dist);
    ...

group('firstGroup').
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    ...
```

Is someone can help me please ?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You have different transition durations, i.e. line 292 of your fiddle should be `.duration(500)`.

Comment: Ioups, I didn't see that, thank you !

Comment: Do you know if the groupTransition or something like that exist is d3 ?

Comment: There's nothing like this in D3.